# What five creatures were sacrificed in Barb & J.C. Hendee's Sister of the Dead?

Tags: books, magical-creatures, noble-dead-saga

In the book *[Sister of the Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_the_Noble_Dead#Series.2FPhase_1)*, Leesil, Magiere & Wynn find a tomb of sorts where a sacrifice took place many years ago. The skeletons of some unknown creatures are found amongst that of a man, elf and dwarf.

> Her gaze passed over one remains to the next, out of control - elf, dwarf, a creature of the air, one of water, and the other… of fire? ...her mind did little more than reiterate her earliest lessons in the structure of creation.
>   The elements are Spirit, Earth, Water, Air, and Fire…
>   Showing states in Essence, Solid, Liquid, Gas, and Energy…
>   To manifest as Tree, Mountain, Wind, Wave, and Flame…
>   And within the chamber were an elf of the forest, a dwarf of the mountains…
>   She did not know the names for the other three. They were so lost back beyond The Forgotten that no one knew them as more than part of the myth of the Uirishg, as the elves called them. The sages translated that word as akin to 'Fay-blooded' or 'Children of the Fay,' but the word was so old that its literal meaning was uncertain.

***Question***: **What were the other three creatures that represented water, air and fire?**

---

**Air**
Her face and build were as lithe and slender as the last prisoner's had been hulking and wide. She would have been slight even standing next to the dead elf. Her eyes had no irises. They were fully black like a sparrow's. From narrow feet to her head of feathery hair, her pale flesh appeared downy, though there were places where it had molted or been rubbed to bare cream skin. There were wings of mottled grays and whites sprouting from her back.

**Water**
Slender but solid of build, the creature had strange rows of spikes stuck out along the back side of its forearms, from each vertebra of its spine, and along its crested skull. The bones were cream-white and had not yellowed beneath its decayed filth. Its teeth were also ridged, but with regularly spaced points. She made a hidden reach for one of the smaller spikes springing from the front of its shin. Her gaze returned to the spikes on its spine, longer near the upper back but growing shorter toward the tailbone. Like the fin of a sea creature.

**Fire**
In place of teeth, its jaws had sharpened ridges, and the final bones of its toes and fingers ended in sharp curved points. It was in a container that measured less than half a man's height in all dimensions and was made of bound steel plates that were discolored and blackened. Steam rose with a sizzling crackle from the damp floor when it was set down, and erratic scraping came from within the metal walls. The frantic noise grew until a screech from the steel made everyone in the room flinch. A villager was freeing a chain used to drag it along and brushed a hand against the discolored metal. The sizzle of his flesh filled the room and he cried out and pulled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Dwarf
2. Dunidæ
3. Séyilf
4. Chein'âs
5. Elf

This gruesome discovery becomes a recurring theme that is built upon and referenced multiple times within the series:

> He and his companions had stumbled upon another of the lost races - the Úirishg - one of the five nonhuman species that were thought to be but a myth. *[Child of a Dead God](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1145177.Child_of_a_Dead_God)*
>
> ---
>
> ...the Chein'âs, the Burning Ones... The Chein'âs lived in the lava-heated depths of the mountains." *[Dog in the Dark](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15808414-the-dog-in-the-dark)*
>
> ---
>
> Half a world away in Droevinka, Leesil had uncovered a hidden chamber... In that chamber, they'd found the remains of those slaughtered for the ritual. Elves and dwarves were known, one of each present among the desiccated bones. But the others were like no beings Wynn had ever seen... A séyilf, one of the Wind-Blown... the Chein'âs, the Burning Ones... Spirit and Earth, Air and Fire. That left only water...the people from the sea, the last race of the Úirishg. *[Through Stone and Sea](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6621880-through-stone-and-sea)*